# Visual Studio 2022 will not let me create a Project for the .NET 4.6.2 Platform

Tags: .net, f#, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to create a simple hello world with F#.
The only condition I need to fullfill is that this Project should run for .NET <= 4.6.2
I've installed various runtimes and SDKs by download and by the Visual Studio Installer.
But still I'm not able when creating a new project to select any other targetframework than .NET 6

[image]

Comment: You're asking for .NET Framework 4.6.2. .NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. If you selected a .NET Core project template you'll only see .NET Core versions

Comment: Besides, why use .NET Framework in the first place? And why .NET Framework 4.6.2? All supported Windows versions have more recent versions. 4.6.2 is the oldest supported .NET Framework version

Comment: You can create project with net6, and then change target framework to `net462` inside fsproj file

Comment: @Panagiotis Yes, probably I could a newer .NET Framework version.
I need to use .NET Framework to use special 3rd party libaries.

@JL0PD I've modified the fsproj file but then i get some errors: 
e.g.: 
`Error NU1202 Package FSharp.Core 6.0.6 is not compatible with net452`

Comment: What special libraries? Are you sure there aren't .NET Standard or .NET Core versions available? Most F# libraries are at least .NET Standard

Comment: Originaly the Libaries are written  in C# and I'm in contact with the responsable developer and therefore pretty sure.

Answer (score 10):

.NET 6 is .NET *Core* 6. If you selected a .NET Core project template you'll only see .NET Core versions.

You need to select a .NET Framework project template.

BTW .NET Framework 4.6.2 is [the oldest supported version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). Supported Windows versions have more recent runtimes.

In the `Create a new project` windows, select `Console Application (.NET Framework)` instead of `Console App`

[image: Console Project templates with .NET Framework highlighted]

Comment: Semantics but, .NET 6 is neither .NET Framework nor .NET Core. It is the successor of both.

Comment: @Jodrell that's marketing, not semantics. Yes, I know the history, the outcry, the confusion and I've answered identical questions a dozen times. There is a huge difference and the source of this confusion. No, .NET 6 isn't the successor of .NET Framework - you can't use .NET Framework assemblies in .NET 6. You can use *all* .NET Core assemblies though.

Comment: @Jodrell yes, Microsoft announced the "unification" of runtimes and the name change years ago, for marketing reasons, so people wouldn't be scared to upgrade to a completely new runtime. There was no unification though. APIs from .NET Framework were migrated to .NET Core, so people could recompile their old code with minimal changes. They couldn't use the binaries, because the SDK and the Runtime were completely different. The only binaries that could be reused were those compiled for .NET Standard (which isn't a runtime)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, netcore and net both ecma335-conforming implementations and can use assemblies compiled for netframework, but their code can crush with MissingMethodException or MissingTypeException because some API are missing or changed

Comment: Seems sensible to me, how to get F# .NET Framework project templates?

Comment: Go back to the project templates list and choose `Console Application (.NET Framework)` instead of `Console App`

Comment: This opiton is simply not showing up ... 
My stunning solution for now is to create a Project with Visual Studio 2017 and open it with Visual Studio 2022 ...
I feel so dirty.

Comment: Have you installed the .NET Framework workload? I posted an actual screenshot of the filters and projects from my Visual Studio installation. The option is there